# Python pdf translate

Tags: python, pdf

Можно ли с помощью python извлечь текст из pdf. Переводит и сунуть в другой pdf

Comment: www.geeksforgeeks.org/working-with-pdf-files-in-python/amp

Answer (score 2):

Для перевода воспользуйтесь Yandex Translate API: https://tech.yandex.ru/translate/ , есть небольшая бесплатная подписка.

Самый простой вариант:

```
from yandex_translate import YandexTranslate
translate = YandexTranslate(YANDEXTRANSLATEKEY)# YANDEXTRANSLATEKEY - токен Яндекса
texttotranslate = '... '
lang=translate.detect(texttotranslate) # определение языка, с которого происходит перевод
if lang=="en":# если нужно на английский переводить
    transketed = texttotranslate
else:
    translated=translate.translate(texttotranslate, lang+'-en')
    translatedtext=translated['text']
```